# How to sense when a winotify action(button) is clicked and then call a function when its clicked

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, notifications

I am aware that the winotify supports opening links,apps etc, but i wanna sense when an action(button) is clicked and then do something(in this case, remove an element from an array) when the button is clicked